# Integrating offbeat theme into magento

Tags: theme, ce-1.9.0.1, wordpress

I've been trying to integrate offbeat theme into magento. It seems that offbeat theme is compatible with `WPML, WooCommerce 2.1.x and Bootstrap 3`. So can anybody give me ideas about integrating wordpress theme into magento? I tried [wpthemeintegration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/), but couldn't figure out about how to use that extension. 
Help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A theme designed for Wordpress/WooCommerce (or any other platform) is not going to be compatible with Magento. The Fishpig extension simply allows Magento to pull content from a Wordpress installation/database and display it. It does not translate a theme for Wordpress into a theme for Magento (as far as I'm aware).

If you wanted to adapt this theme for Magento, then the question you're basically asking is "how do I develop websites?"

---

I think this question is a bit open ended, since the process would be different for any generic WooCommerce/Wordpress theme and the type of store you want to run with Magento.

When it comes down to it, a developer would likely spend near the same amount of time adapting these themes for Magento as they would building a custom theme. If your intention is to be frugal with development costs, you would be better served to simply use a theme actually designed for Magento.

As for how to do it? Who doesn't like a car analogy? Picture two related, but dissimilar vehicles; say an American 4-door sedan and a German 4-door sedan diesel. What if you wanted to take all the engine components from both cars and swap them? Could it be done? Sure. You break each down into smaller components and find what is analogous to what.

I have not worked with WooCommerce at all, but I imagine they have a product page similar to a Magento product page. You will have an image, a title, a price, an add to cart button, etc. WooCommerce might have all of that information in a single template file, while Magento has that information in possibly a dozen or more templates. How would you piece them together? Now do that for all the other pages you need to work on ...

Comment: So my question is "How do I develop websites?" :D I want to adapt this theme for magento